# Secure preferences or database file in the data directory

Tags: android, security, sharedpreferences, android-sqlite

I have been creating an app in Android recently, which has a login page. It's fully offline, so online or network-based solutions would not help me. I think there are two approach for me to accomplish this task.

- Saving password hash in the preferences XML file
- Saving password hash in the SQLite database

However, in my opinion both of these ways could be insecure because an user could load my app's data directory in a DDMS and then take out my preferences or database file and subsequently try to manipulate it.

Now, my question is:

Is there any fully secure approach (preferably not using files) or way to *encrypt* preference or database file?

Thanks in advance

**SOLUTION** (idea from [Marcin Orlowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1235698/marcin-orlowski))

A relatively secure solution would be hashing password along with another string, which is only known to my app (with assumption of no resereve engineering), with this conditions, the attack could not replace my hashed string with his own hashed string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no bullet proof solution. What's in the app can be extracted with more or less efforts or your app can be hacked/etc. If you need to store password, do not store plain as plain text. Do `sha1` or `md5` hash of it first and store the hash, so even if one would get hands on your prefs/DB then he still does not know the password (but he can try to brute force it using i.e. [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) etc). Depending on sensivity of data you protect with password, using hash may be sufficient (if you do not encrypt data itself, then it makes no sense to go further)

Comment: Thanks for your response, "*...using hash may be sufficient...*", In my opinion, *no* it is not sufficient, suppose an attacker replace my hashed string with his own one, then he can easily log in my app.

Comment: only if you'd calculate hash from password string alone. But you add something to it he will not get it unless doing reverse engeneering of your code

Answer (score 0):

Save the password hash in the private ContentProvider. SharedPreferences XML and Database file can only be get from DDMS if user uses rooted phone.

Comment: The base repository of `ContentProvider`s are also databases or files, which are also subjected to this issue.